# How to prove that $2^{3^x} - 1$ not divided by $3k+2$ for all $x$ and $k$?

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that $2^{3^x} - 1$ not divided by $3k+2$ for all $x$ and $k$?
I proved only that $2^{3^x} - 1$ divided by $7$ for all $x \geqslant 1$, but this didn't help me.

Comment: what are you tring to ask

Comment: @BlaiseThunderstorm It's fairly clear what he's asking. Don't need to belittle users whose English isn't as strong as yours.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 fully agree.

Comment: is he meant (not divisible)

Comment: @BlaiseThunderstorm Either would give the same meaning wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $2^{3^n}-1$.  We note that the order of $2$ $\pmod p$ is a divisor of $3^n$, hence it is $3^m$ for some $m\ge 1$.  Thus $3^m\,|\,p-1$ .  It follows that $p$ is of the form $3k+1$ and your claim follows at once.

Comment: Thank u, this helped me! :)

Comment: @user401689 Be sure to understand why $\,m\neq 0\,$ above (a case which *can* occur for bases $>2,\,$ e.g. $\, 3\mid 4^{\large 3^n}\!-1)\ \ $